# Page Builder is not visible magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, page, home, page-builder

It must be here so I could enable it but its not.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRkiZ.png

what can I do?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNETr.png
Its not here as well. please help.

Comment: Okay as it seems it is only available for Magento commerce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page Builder is a Magento Commerce extension, it is **not included** with Magento Open Source.

More information on Page Builder is available here https://devdocs.magento.com/page-builder/docs/

Comment: Is it expensive? If you know.

Comment: You cannot purchase it as a separate module, it is a part of Magento Commerce, and requires a Magento Commerce license.